# Save non-persistent object id in JPA (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, jpa-2.0

I've a static class like:

```
public class Sex{

private final int code;
private final String status;

public static final int TOTAL = 3;

private Sex(int c, String s) {
code = c;
status = s;
}

public static final Sex UNDEFINED = new Sex(1, "UNDEFINED");
public static final Sex MALE = new Sex(2, "MALE");
public static final Sex FEMALE = new Sex(3, "FEMALE");
private static final Sex[] list = { UNDEFINED, MALE, FEMALE };

public int getCode() {
return code;
}

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public static Sex fromInt(int c) {
if (c < 1 || c > TOTAL)
throw new RuntimeException("Unknown code for fromInt in Sex");
return list[c-1];
}

public static List getSexList() {
return Arrays.asList(list);
}
}
```

And, I've an entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")

public class Person{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;// setter/getter omitted

    private Sex sex;
    public final Sex getSex() {
    return this.sex;
    }
    public final void setSex(final Sex argSex) {
    this.sex = argSex;
    }
}
```

I want to save `sex_id` in database in person table. But setter/getter should be as specified, because I want write my code as -

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setSex(Sex.MALE);
Dao.savePerson(person);
```

How to annotate `Sex` with JPA?

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't want to create new `Sex` instance in your database, why don't you use an `enum` instead of a `class` for `Sex`?

If you do so, you will just have to annotate you `Sex` attribute with `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` in the `Person` class. Full example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/EnumeratedValueMappingEnumTypeSTRING.htm) (or just Google it and you will find plenty)

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use enumerator Sex instead and then use `@Enumerated` instead?

```
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   Sex sex
```